# How to remove special character from string when post to database?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, special-characters

I have AngularJs tooltip for character counter where i am facing two problems.

1- Because of special character in the string its not saving it to db when copy paste below text in the text area.

2- It should only add 4000 character in the text area more than that should be escaped.

I have tried below code if i add more than 4000 character its going beyond 4000 and characters left is showing negative numbers in count and also failed to save.

How to resolve these problems ?

Ctrl.js

```
 $scope.$watch('processDTO.processStatementText', function () {
              if (!$scope.processDTO.processStatementText) { 
                $scope.processStatementTextTooltip = '4000'; 
                }
              else { 
                $scope.processStatementTextTooltip = 4000 - $scope.processDTO.processStatementText.replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g,'\r\n').length ;
                }
            });
```

main.html

```
<textarea rows="2" class="form-control"
                ng-model="processDTO.processStatementText"
                name="processStatement" id="processStatement"
                placeholder="Process Statement" maxlength="4000" required
                tooltip="{{processStatementTextTooltip}} characters left"
                tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'focus', false: 'never'}[processDTO.processStatementText.length >= 0 || processDTO.processStatementText.length == null ]}}"
                tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-class="bluefill">
            </textarea>
```

Text.txt

```
2.  Upload Template Header – Risk Causal and Impact comments are color coded as mandatory but they are optional. Similary the Originating Source System Process/Risk/control ID
3.  In the upload template, for any of the multi value fields, I use an invalid delimiter ‘:’, Eg: 13:7 , for some reason this changes the cell format to time format and thereafter I am not able to give any single values, its always converted to time format. Not sure if this is a training issue, but want to put it on the table to see if it requires any fix at all
4.  In Upload, for the grid field length validations, the filter doesn’t works on Row Number and Max Allowed columns.
5.  ERH All levels added in the View End to End ERH screen – Sort and Filter doesn’t works, After clicking on this field, none of the other filter/sort works on the page. Also the sort indicator(black triangle) is not visible, I believe the column width needs to be adjusted.
6.  The Risk/Control reference id is seen on the Process Search grids, but when I search by Risk/Control, I don’t see the corresponding control/risk grid having the ref id column however tool tip has it
7.  The label change “Originating Source System Process/Risk/Control ID” is not done in View/Search Inventory tool tips of Process, Risk, Control grids, It has to be fixed for all the 3 searches “By Process/Risk/Control”
2.  Upload Template Header – Risk Causal and Impact comments are color coded as mandatory but they are optional. Similary the Originating Source System Process/Risk/control ID
3.  In the upload template, for any of the multi value fields, I use an invalid delimiter ‘:’, Eg: 13:7 , for some reason this changes the cell format to time format and thereafter I am not able to give any single values, its always converted to time format. Not sure if this is a training issue, but want to put it on the table to see if it requires any fix at all
4.  In Upload, for the grid field length validations, the filter doesn’t works on Row Number and Max Allowed columns.
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue on your server...

Comment: I want to escape special character client side

Comment: So does that mean you will still have a SQL injection problem on the server? Have you figured out what characters is actually breaking it?

Comment: you should do it on both because users can always turn off javascript :)

Comment: escaping should be done server side. No reason to do escaping in client

Comment: @aemorales1 If they turn off JS, the OP has a bigger problem since it is a JS powered app. ;)

Comment: @epascarello: indeed

Comment: ok lets assume we have server side escaping that problem is resolved issue # 1 but my tooltip still has a problem its not counting special characters and restrict user to 4000 limit.

Comment: well in your tooltip you are replacing the special characters with a line break when you are checking the length?